# Time Period of one Cycle is way too large

Tags: frequency, time-frequency

I am calculating Time period of Sine/Cos Wave with different frequencies while keeping the Sampling Frequency at 1MHz and plotting it, but in some cases the value of time period is too big,

have a look at some of the examples.

```
n=[0:0.1:10] %because Time period is 10

F1=100*10^3; %100KHz  and t=1*10^-5
Fs=1*10^6;  %1MHz => Sampling Frequency
T=1/Fs;    %1*10^-6

%Time period = t/T => 10

xn=cos(2*pi*(F1)*n*T)   %T=1/Fs
stem(n,xn);

ylim([-1.5 1.5]);
xlim ([0 10]); %because Time period is 10
grid on;
```

Here Time period = 10 which means one oscillation would take 10seconds to complete.
and here is the output as i expected,

[image]

Similarly in second case when i changed the frequency to 10Hz while the Sampling frequency remains 1MHz the value of Time period is way too big,

```
n=[0:1000:100*10^3] %because Time period is 100*10^3

F1=10; %10Hz  and t=0.1
Fs=1*10^6  %1MHz
T=1/Fs;    %1*10^-6

%Time period = t/T => 100*10^3

xn=sin(2*pi*(F1)*n*T)

stem(n,xn)

ylim([-1.5 1.5])
xlim ([0 100*10^3])  %because Time period is 100*10^3
ylim ([-1 1])
grid on
```

and the output wave is,

[image]

is it the correct value or am i doing some sort mistakes calculating the time period ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation `xn=cos(2*pi*(F1)*n*T)` expects `n` to be a sample index vector (`n=0:N`) where `N` is the total number of samples.  `n*T` or `n/Fs` produces the time vector.

Here is a way to plot a single cycle:

```
F1 = 100e3;
Fs = 1e6;
t = 0:(1/Fs):1/F1;  %Creates time vector for a single cycle
x = cos(2*pi*F1*t);
stem(t, x);
```

Note that `1/F1` gives the time period of a single cycle.